# For Loop - TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, replace

I am a little confused trying to create a for loop.

I have a dataframe with some Tweets informations, and there are 2 columns that I need for this for loop: `tweet_id` and `expanded_urls`.
I have some cases in my dataframe that the expanded_urls are not complete, they are only 'twitter.com/xxx/status/'. But the correct link has the tweet ID after the status, something like: twitter.com/xxx/status/1234567890

So, I have tried this:

```
for i in line:
    twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'] = np.where(twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'] == 'https://twitter.com/xxx/status/', ('https://twitter.com/xxx/status/'+ twitter_archive_master.tweet_id), twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'])
```

So I am picking every line with this incomplete URL and trying to add their ID, but I am getting this error:

`TypeError: must be str, not int`

What am I doing wrong?

Both columns are object.

Comment: `('https://twitter.com/xxx/status/'+ twitter_archive_master.tweet_id)` maybe this needs to be explicitly made a str?

Comment: Yeah, the tweet id is not a string. It's being returned as an int, so it needs to be explicitly cast; adding a string and an int won't implicitly cast. You can use string interpolation, formatted strings, or f-strings if you'd like instead as well, e.g. `'http://url.com/{:d}'.format(tweet_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert id to string type

```
for i in line:
    twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'] = np.where(twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'] == 
                                                       https://twitter.com/xxx/status/',
                                                       ('https://twitter.com/xxx/status/'
                                                        +
                                                        str(twitter_archive_master.tweet_id)),
                                                       twitter_archive_master['expanded_urls'])
```

Comment: Check out [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to ensure readability across all platforms and also better integration with accessibility tools.

Comment: Oh... perfect!! It worked... why should I convert it to str if it is already STR? any thoughts? Maybe because its a number and If I dont tell is a str, python doesn't know?